# How to make positioning in html and css so that it is okay in all the devices?

Tags: html, css

```css
.first_bar
{
 background-color:rgb(59, 89, 152);
 height:80px;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:-39px;
 margin-left:-5px;
 
 
}
.name
{
 font-size:40px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-style:cursive;
 color:white;
 margin-left:190px;
 padding-top:20px;
 
}


.gyan
{
 color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 29px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 450px;
    word-spacing: -1px;
 margin-left:200px;
}
.img
{
 margin-left:200px;
 width: 450px;
 
 
}
.information
{
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 right:240px;
 bottom:280px;
 
}
.box
 {
 border:1px solid black;
 width:120px;
 height:20px;
 background-color:white;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 left:790px;
 bottom:100px;
 }
.boxhead
 {
 border:1px solid rgb(59, 89, 152);
 width:120px;
 height:20px;
 
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 left:790px;
 bottom:100px;
 color:white;
 word-spacing:-2px;
 font-style:helvetica;
 font-weight:-1px;
 
 }
.boxlogin
 {
 border:1px solid black;
 width:60px;
 height:20px;
 background-color:rgb(139,157,195);
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 left:800px;
 bottom:125px;
 color:white;
 font-style:helvetica;
 }
.boxheadniche
 {
  
 border:1px solid rgb(59, 89, 152);
 width:120px;
 height:13px;
 background-color:rgb(59, 89, 152);
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 left:790px;
 bottom:125px;
 color:white;
 word-spacing:-2px;
 font-style:helvetica;
 font-size:15px;
  
 }
 .informationextra
 {
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 right:-110px;
 bottom:150px;
 list-style-type:none;
 font-size:20px;
 }
 .adddata
 {
  border:1px solid rgb(189, 199, 216);
  height:25px;
  width:170px;
  background-color:white;
  font-style:Arial;
  color:#c0c0c0;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  word-spacing:-1px;
  font-size:15px;
  
 }
 .adddataextra
 {
  border:1px solid rgb(189, 199, 216);
  height:25px;
  width:340px;
  background-color:white;
  font-style:Arial;
  color:#c0c0c0;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  word-spacing:-1px;
  font-size:15px;
  margin-top:10px;
 }
 .surname
 {
  border:1px solid rgb(189, 199, 216);
  height:25px;
  width:145px;
  background-color:white;
  font-style:Arial;
  font-size:15px;
  color:#c0c0c0;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  word-spacing:-1px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  left:505px;
  bottom:130px;
 }
 .informationbirthday
 {
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  top:50px;
  left:500px;
  font-style:helvetica;
  
  
  
 }
 .birthday
 {
  border:1px solid rgb(189, 199, 216);
  height:20px;
  width:60px;
  font-style:helvetica;
 }
 .birthdaymonth
 {
  border:1px solid rgb(189, 199, 216);
  height:20px;
  width:70px;
  font-style:helvetica;
 }
 .birthdayyear
 {
  border:1px solid rgb(189, 199, 216);
  height:20px;
  width:55px;
  font-style:helvetica;
 }
 .reason
 {
  position:relative;
  height:20px;
  width:150px;
  font-style:helvetica;
  font-size:12px;
  color:rgb(59, 89, 152);
  top:-23px;
  top:-23px;
  left:200px;
 }
 .gender
 {
  position:relative;
  left:790px;
  bottom:50px;
  clear:both;
 }
 .caution
 {
  font-size:15px;
  font-style:Arial;
  color:grey;
  width:500px;
  height:10px;
  
 }
 .button
 {
  height:30px;
  width:220px;
  background-color:#69a74e;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  color:white;
  right:300px;
  border:1px solid rgb(59, 89, 152);
  border-radius:5px;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:7px;
  font-weight:bold;
  word-spacing:2px;
  
 }
 .line
 {
  position:relative;
  left:800px;
  top:50px;
  color:grey;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 .link
 {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#0e385f;
 }
 .link:hover,.boxheadniche:hover,.reason:hover
 {
  text-decoration:underline; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook-Log In or Sign up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="facebook.css">
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/fb-art.jpg">
</head>
<body>
<div class="first_bar">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><p class="name">facebook</p></a>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="boxhead";>Email or phone</th>
<th></th>
<th class="boxhead">Password</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="box"></td>
<td></td>
<td class="box"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td><form><input class="boxlogin" type="submit" value="Log In" ></form></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
<td class="boxheadniche"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate?lwv=110" style="color:white;text-decoration:none;"> Having Trouble?</a></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div >
<p class="gyan">Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in your life.</p>


<img class="img" src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yx/r/pyNVUg5EM0j.png"/>
</div>
<div class="information">
<h1 style="font-size:40px">Create an account</h1>
<p style="font-size:20px;word-spacing:-1px;"><strong>It's free and will always be.</strong></p>
</div>

<div>
<form>
<ul class="informationextra">
<li ><input class="adddata" type="text" name="first" value="First Name"></li>
<li><input class="adddataextra" type="text" name="first" value="Enter Mobile Number or email address"></li>
<li><input class="adddataextra" type="text" name="reenter" value="Re-enter Mobile number or email address"></li>
<li><input class="adddataextra" type="text" name="reenter" value="New Password"></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
<form>
<div>
<input class="surname" type="text" name="surname" value="Surname">


</div>
</form>
<div class="informationbirthday">
<h2>Birthday</h2>
<select class="birthday">
     <option>Day</option>
     <option>1</option> 
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option> 
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option>
     <option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option>
     <option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option>

    </select>
 <select class="birthdaymonth">
        <option>Month</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
    </select>
    <select class="birthdayyear">
        <option>year</option><option>2016</option><option>2015</option><option>2014</option><option>2013</option><option>2012</option><option>2011</option><option>2010</option>
        <option>2009</option><option>2008</option><option>2007</option><option>2006</option><option>2005</option><option>2004</option><option>2003</option><option>2002</option>
        <option>2001</option><option>2000</option><option>1999</option><option>1998</option><option>1997</option><option>1996</option><option>1995</option><option>1994</option>
        <option>1993</option><option>1992</option><option>1991</option><option>1991</option><option>1990</option><option>1989</option><option>1988</option><option>1987</option>
        <option>1986</option><option>1985</option><option>1984</option><option>1983</option><option>1982</option><option>1981</option><option>1980</option>

    </select>
 <div class="reason"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#3b5998;">Why do I need to provide my date of birth?</a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="gender">
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
   
</form> 

<p class="caution">By clicking Create an account, you agree to our <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms" >Terms</a> 
and that you have read our <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy">Data Policy</a>,
 including our <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/help/cookies" >Cookie Use.</a></p>
</div>
<div class="button">
Create an Account
</div>
<div class="line">
<p>____________________________________________</p>
<p><a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/?ref_type=registration_form" style="">Create a page</a> for a fan,celebrity or business.</p>



</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I use `px` to set the dimensions and other stuff. I have a problem with positioning of elements due to which I am unable to create anything. My page is not responsive to devices of different sizes. I had to submit an assignment using HTML and CSS only. I created it according to the dimensions of my screen. But it's a complete mess up in other devices. What do I do?

Comment: use em instead of px

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp also try to use more %

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added the required html and css file ..u can check

Comment: Have a google for media queries - it makes the site responsive to different browser sizes

Comment: I have read about media queries..but it is for the part when I change the size of my browser.My problem is while zooming in/out.You can run my codes and see the problem

Comment: Questions begin with capitals and ends with a "?" on English. You can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about here is called Responsive Design.

It is an extremely complicated matter, but can be shortened into a few key components. You should probably read up on Responsive HTML & CSS and see if that will help you.

What you are basically doing, is making sure that the sizes change according to the device.

Currently, your CSS will most likely contain specific sizes for `div` objects et cetera. What you are looking for, is to size them to like 50%, which will be a great place to start.

I recommend you read a little on the subject here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites. It gives you the ability to easily create responsive designs.

> Responsive web design is about creating web sites which automatically adjust themselves to look good on all devices, from small phones to large desktops.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Include this link in header section  and
use `class="col-sm-x"` in div section.(The value of x can be any number - refer bootstrap grid system [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp))

Bootstrap will help you to create a responsive page for every device.

Refer Below links for more details.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/

Comment: 1)my first problem is while I zoom in/out in a particular device.. my page distorts      2)my second problem is the different devices..3)I have to complete my task using html and css only.Don't know about Bootstrap till now.